# Não consigo imprimir uma variável que recebe o valor de uma posição de lista

Tags: python

Exercício de listas.

Selecione o maior e o menor elemento de um vetor.

```
import os
os.system("clear")
vetor=[] #declara o vetor
#solicita o n° de elementos
n = int(input("Digite a quantidade de elementos a ser adicionada.."))
#declara o i
i = 0
#recebe os elementos do vetor (numeros inteiros)
while (i<n):    
    temp = int(input("Digite o elemento a ser adicionado.."))
    vetor.append(temp)#vetor na última posição recebe o valor salvo em temp
    i=i+1
print(vetor)
#Reiniciando o i
i=0
#declara variáveis menor e maior
menor = vetor[0]
maior = vetor[0]
#Laço de seleção do menor e do maior valor
while (i<n):    
    if vetor[i]<menor:
        menor=vetor[i]
    if vetor[i]>maior:
        maior=vetor[i]
        i=i+1
#Imprime o resultado
print("Vetor dado: ", vetor)
print("Menor valor: ", menor)
print("Maior valor: ", maior)
```

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não fazemos trabalhos de casa uns pelos outros.

Comment: Realmente. Concordo com @Omni. Me parece um mau uso do site e uma péssima maneira de se aprender a programar.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ser sobre trabalho de casa, está no escopo sim: o autor _fez_ o trabalho e tem um erro em sua lógica que está quase corrteta-  só pede ajuda para encontrar o erro. 

É muito diferente de quem só coloca o enunciado e espera que os outros escrevam o programa todo, e está completamente dentro do escopo e do espírito do S.O.

Comment: @Alex: quando for postar alguma dúvida, além da listagem, ponha também o que está dando errado. Nesse caso seria "o programa fica parado sem fazer nada". Quando tiver um erro, a mensagem de erro é importante. Escreva sobre o que você fez, e o que acha que pode ser o erro - não ponha só o enunciado da questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lógica do seu programa está correta - você aparentemente só se confundiu a respeito da natureza dos blocos em Python - todos as linhas identadas pra frente, depois de um comando que termina em `:` fazem parte de um bloco que será executado ou repetido em conjunto, dependendo daquele comando. No caso do `if` todas as linhas indentadas para frente só serão executadas se a condição for verdadeira. A maior parte das outras linguagens em uso hoje herdou a sintaxe da linguagem `C` e usa chaves para delimitar esses blocos - (`{` e `}`).

No caso da sua listagem, perceba que você só está incrementando o valor de `i` se a segunda condição for verdadeira:

```
while (i<n): 
    ...
    if vetor[i]>maior:
        maior=vetor[i]
        i=i+1
```

E assim, o valor de `i` nunca fica igual a `n` e seu programa fica preso indefinidamente no laço  `while`. Deixe a linha `i = i + 1` alinahda embaixo do `if`, e ela será exercutada para todo elemento da lista, e seu programa será executado normalmente.

Dito isso, observe que enquanto que esse programa seja legal quando comparado a um programa equivalente em C ou Pascal, Python é uma linguagem que torna o básico da programação realmente básico. Bom, além das coisas que usamos "a sério" no dia a dia, que são as funções embutidas `min`e `max` que respondem o maior e menor valor de uma única vez, como bem aponta a resposta do Órion, há algumas dicas para você verificar ai, sem precisar curto-circuitar seu programa todo:

Em Python, o laço `for` sempre percorre todos os elementos de uma sequência - não precisa do valor numérico `i` como índice da sequência. Uma vez que seus números estão na lista de nome `vetor`, basta fazer:

```
for elemento in vetor:
    if elemento > maior:
        ...
    if elemento < menor:
        ...
```

Perceba que desta forma você não rpecisa da variável a mais `i`, nem escrever `vetor[i]` - o  for já recuperar cada elento do `vetor` na variável `elemento`. Teria mais alguams dicas - mas o melhor mesmo agora é você praticar e ir descobrindo as coisas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, resposta bem completa! Consegui resolver o problema por outros meios e esqueci que a havia publicado aqui. Agradeço novamente!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode retornar o menor e o maior valor usando `min()` e `max()` respectivamente.

**Exemplo:**

```
vetor = []

quantidade = int(input('Digite a quantidade de elementos: '))

for i in range(quantidade):
    elemento = int(input('Digite o elemento: '))
    vetor.append(elemento)

print('Vetor: ', vetor)
print('Menor valor: ', min(vetor))
print('Maior valor: ', max(vetor))
```

**Com menos linhas:**

```
quantidade = int(input('Digite a quantidade de elementos: '))
vetor = [int(input('Digite o elemento: ')) for i in range(quantidade)]
print('Vetor: ', vetor)
print('Menor valor: ', min(vetor))
print('Maior valor: ', max(vetor))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui resolver o problema por outros meios e esqueci que a havia publicado aqui. Agradecido!